# Open the created word document after saved to the server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, ms-word

I am using ASP.NET to create Word documents.

On the client side, after clicking a button, the Word document will be created and saved to the server. Also, right after the document is created, Word opens the created document from the client side.

I have the following code which works on the local server, but if I upload the application to the server, the document will be created to the folder on the server, but Word does not open the saved file automatically.

I think I have the wrong path to retrieve the file, but I could not fix it. Any thoughts? Thanks.

```
 string filename = Server.MapPath("Template/Template.docx");
 string fileNameTemplate = "SteelSpec-{0}.docx";
 string outputFileName = string.Format(fileNameTemplate, specno);

// .... (template modifying)

 template.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Document/" + outputFileName));
 Process.Start("WINWORD.EXE", Server.MapPath("~/" + outputFileName));
```

Comment: You need to serve it as a download.

Comment: You can't run programs on the client.

Comment: Process.Start is absolutely never going to work. This will run on the server, and the server only. In testing it will work for you because your local development machine is both the server and the client.
Also, hosts and server admins never ever ever want to see Word running on a server. Office is not meant to be installed on a server, and the threading model is entirely wrong to be called from a web application and Microsoft has advised against this for over 15 years.